# trazer menus e submenus ativos C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Tenho que fazer uma consulta pelo o menu que tenho que trazer somente os submenus ativos, veja o meu código.

```
return context.Set<Menu>().Include("MenuGroups")
              .Where(x => x.Id == id && x.MenuGroups.Any(z => z.Active))
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

meu retorno continua trazendo meus submenus com o *status* `false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem que instalar um pacote para adicionar a funcionalidade de filtros no `include`, instale:

> `PM> Install-Package Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6`

adicione a referencia do pacote:

```
using Z.EntityFramework.Plus;
```

depois codifique:

```
return context.Set<Menu>()
              .IncludeFilter(x => x.MenuGroups.Where(z => z.Active == true))
              .Where(x => x.Id == id)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [EntityFramework Plus (EF6)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6/)
- [EF Query IncludeFilter | Entity Framework Include Related Entities using Where Filter](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Query-IncludeFilter-%7C-Entity-Framework-Include-Related-Entities-using-Where-Filter)