# Como pegar entidades filhas a partir de uma restrição de dado?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm

Bom meu problema é o seguinte, preciso trazer uma entidade do banco e ela contém diversas listas que devem trazer seus dados seguindo uma regra, o campo `data_exclusao` deve ser nulo.

Todas as entidades possuem o campo `data_exclusao` que representa a exclusão logica do dado. Então segue um exemplo para ficar melhor eu tenho a entidade pessoa e nela contém as listas de entidades `endereco` e telefone. Quando eu for buscar a entidade pessoa do banco ela deve trazer todos os *endereços* e *telefones* onde a `data_exclusao` é igual a `null`.

Utilizo o EF e gostaria de saber onde aplico essa regra para que seja genérica, ou seja todas as buscas do banco sempre tragam os dados onde o campo `data_exclusao` for igual a `null`.

***Observação:*** gero o modelo de dados através do `EDMX` e a versão do `EF` que uso é o `EF6`.

Comment: A versão do seu Entity Framework por favor?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic a versão que estou usando é o EF6

Comment: é mais ou menos isso: https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/soft-deleting-entities-cleanly-using-entity-framework-6-interceptors.html

Comment: Essa funcionalidade foi adotada pela versão `Entity Framework Core` com o nome de Global Query Filter onde automaticamente era executado isso em todas as Entitdades Configuradas, na Versão 6 tem que ser um plugin me parece ... estou procurando.

Comment: Outro exemplo:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933981/entity-framework-soft-delete-implementation-using-database-interceptor-not-worki

Comment: Valeu, vou dar uma olhada agora.

Comment: Deu certo Guilherme?

Comment: Ainda não tive tempo para implementar, assim que fizer posto o  resultado aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maneira de contornar um recurso inexistente até o momento na versão [Entity Farmework 6.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/) é utilizando o ***pacotes***:

- [Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6/)
- [Z.EntityFramework.Plus.QueryIncludeFilter.EF6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.QueryIncludeFilter.EF6/)

Com esses dois pacotes é adicionado o recurso em filtrar automaticamente em todas as `SQL` das entidades configuradas a execução de filtros **Globais**.

Um exemplo minimo:

***Entidade:***

```
public partial class Funcionario
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataExclusao { get; set; }
}
```

Como vai funcionar todas as `SQL` onde o filtro Global é `DataExclusao IS NULL`, então para funcionar adicione o `namespace`:

```
using Z.EntityFramework.Plus;
```

no Contrutor da sua classe que herda do `DbContext`, escreve essa linha de código:

```
this.Filter<Funcionario>(x => x.Where(a => a.DataExclusao == null));
```

***Código completo:***

```
public partial class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext()
        :base(@"Data Source=.\SqlExpress; ...")
    {
        this.Filter<Funcionario>(x => x.Where(a => a.DataExclusao == null));
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Funcionario> Funcionario { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Funcionario>()
            .ToTable("Funcionario");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Funcionario>()
            .Property(e => e.DataExclusao).HasColumnType("datetime");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Funcionario>()
            .Property(e => e.Nome)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
```

Após essa configuração instancie a classe e utilize como por exemplo:

```
using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var c = db.Funcionario.ToArray();
}
```

a `SQL` que foi debugada é a seguinte:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Nome] AS [Nome], 
    [Extent1].[DataExclusao] AS [DataExclusao]
    FROM [dbo].[Funcionario] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[DataExclusao] IS NULL
```

se por acaso não quizer utilizar os filtros em algum momento no seu código, utilize o método de extensão `AsNoFilter()`, exemplo:

```
var c = db.Funcionario.AsNoFilter().ToArray();
```

<sub>***Outros exemplos:***</sub>

- [trazer menus e submenus ativos C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180851/trazer-menus-e-submenus-ativos-c/180860#180860)
- [Como criar filtros default com entity framework 6?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263804/como-criar-filtros-default-com-entity-framework-6)

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6 - Query Filter](http://entityframework-plus.net/tutorial-query#query-filter)
- [Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6/)
- [Z.EntityFramework.Plus.QueryIncludeFilter.EF6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.QueryIncludeFilter.EF6/)